# Decrypt RC8032 PGP with Bouncy Castle .NET

Tags: c#, .net, gnupg, openpgp, eddsa

I am trying to decrypt a given PGP message with Bouncy Castle .NET.
I have a string for the message, a stream for the private key, and a string for the passphrase.
Looking online, it looks like the first thing to do with the key is the following:

```
var keyStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(keyIn);
PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpSec = new PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(keyStream);
```

But I am getting the exception:

> System.IO.IOException: 'unknown PGP public key algorithm encountered'

I used this useful tool https://cirw.in/gpg-decoder/ to find out more about my key and it looks like the Secret Key Packet and Signature Packet, have the unknown algorithm 0x16. I found a single source that said it is referring to RFC8032 but I am not quite sure.

I can't share my key but I found someone online who shared a throw-away key that looks to be in the same format [here](https://cirw.in/gpg-decoder/#-----BEGIN%20PGP%20PRIVATE%20KEY%20BLOCK-----%0A%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V0+2-----END%20PGP%20PRIVATE%20KEY%20BLOCK-----)

Is this algorithm simply not supported by Bouncy Castle? Is there any way to decrypt messages with this types of keys in .NET?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue.  Wondering if you ever got this solved.  Thanks.

Comment: @InbetweenWeekends BouncyCastle updated and fixed this in the newest version, try to see if it works https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.Cryptography

Comment: Sure enough!  I was using a branched nuget, and it was pretty old.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed in the newest BouncyCastle (2.0) https://www.nuget.org/packages/BouncyCastle.Cryptography