# EncryptionKeys doesn't read pub.rsa format

Tags: c#, encryption, signature, public-key

The following code:

```
FileInfo pubKey = new FileInfo("pub.rsa");
EncryptionKeys encryptionKeys = new EncryptionKeys(pubKey);
FileInfo file = new FileInfo("example.csv.sig");
PGP pgp = new PGP(encryptionKeys);
pgp.VerifyClearFile(file);
```

returns an error

```
System.IO.IOException: 'unknown PGP public key algorithm encountered'
```

How can I fix this? Is it possible to use pub.rsa public key format there at all?

Comment: same issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70790516/decrypt-rc8032-pgp-with-bouncy-castle-net

Comment: Looks similar but still without a solution